# match-* functions not behaving?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a elisp function that marks a Python test function as green or red depending on the input. The arguments are pretty self-explanatory. The navigation part works, but the `put-text-property` part simply does nothing. I've tried `eval`-ing the `match-*` functions, but I cannot make sense of the return values. They also seem to return different things depending on which buffer i `eval` in.

The basic gist of this is borrowed from a relevant part of [rainbow-mode.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/elpa.git/tree/packages/rainbow-mode/rainbow-mode.el#n1000), and in there it works flawlessly.

What's wrong with the `put-text-property` call? Relatedly, what can I do to debug this and learn more?

````
(defun snake-decorate-test (file class func status)
  ; FIXME: Path hardcoded while developing.
  (find-file (format "/home/thiderman/git/piper/%s" file))
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (re-search-forward (format "^class %s(" class) nil t)
  (re-search-forward (format "^    def \\(%s\\)(" func) nil t)
  (put-text-property
   (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
   'face `((:background ,(if (s-equals? status ".")
                             "#007200" "#720000")))))```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is that buffer font-locked? If so, try using `font-lock-face` instead of `face` as the text property.  Font lock is greedy - it wipes out (overrides) any `face` highlighting you add.
2. Have you tried to debug it?

   a. Have you used `C-u C-x =` on a character that you expect should be highlighted by your code?  You might find that it does in fact have the `face` property you tried to give it, but font lock is overriding that highlighting (see #1).

   b. Use `M-x debug-on-entry snake-decorate-test` and then walk through the function using `d` (occasionally `c`, to skip through a step). Use `e` anytime to evaluate any sexp and see the return value.

   c. Alternatively, add calls to `message` that print out intermediate state that you want to check, so you can see what is happening.  E.g., show yourself what `(match-beginning 1)` really is, to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: The first suggestion worked! That's awesome! Thanks a lot! :D

Also, thanks for the debugging tips. I'm fairly new to emacs efter spending the better part of a decade in vim and finally transferring over. Elisp is awesome but difficult to grasp in situations like debugging. Your tips will be treasured!